# How do I get netcat to accept connections from outside the LAN?

Tags: gateway, portforwarding, netcat

I'm using netcat as a backend to shovel data back and forth for a program I'm making. I tested my program on the local network, and once it worked I thought it would be a matter of simply forwarding a port from my router to have my program work over the internet. Alas! This seems not to be the case.

If I start netcat listening on port 6666 with:

`nc -vv -l -p 6666`,

then go to `127.0.0.1:6666` in a browser, as expected I see a HTTP GET request come through netcat (and my browser sits waiting in vain). If I go to `my.external.ip.address:6666`, however, nothing comes through at all and the browser displays 'could not connect to `my.external.ip.address:6666`'.

I know that the port is correctly forwarded, as www.canyouseeme.org says port 6666 is open (and when netcat is not listening, that its closed).

If I run netcat with `-g my.adslmodem's.local.address` to set the gateway address, I get the same behavior. Am I using this command line option correctly? Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Turns out there is no problem. It only appears that way because my router doesn't allow hairpin connections. That is, even though I've got it set up correctly, the router wouldn't make the connection when both source and destination are behind the NAT. Simply `ncat -l -p 6666` works fine, so long as the request comes from outside the LAN. To test this I browsed to `my.external.ip.address:6666` with my 3G mobile phone and sure enough, a HTTP request came through :)

This answer came from: [a serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35496/access-tomcat-from-outside-lan), which is where I should have asked this question in the first place. Apologies for that.

Comment: Hah. No worries. I asked a similar question on SF and they thought it was too newbish. I couldn't tell what a "hairpin" connection was (and people kept referencing "hairpin NAT" and telling me to RTFM) until I just read this answer. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for me too. I didn't use 0.0.0.0. As you said, only port on target machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

You must listen on the public interface. You're currently listening on localhost where no one outside of your computer can connect.

Your milage may vary, but with my implementation of [netcat](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/nc.1.html) I have to use this command line to listen on all the public interfaces.

`netcat -vv -l 0.0.0.0 6666`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that's the case, as netcat happily receives connections from other computers on my network. Also when it starts it displays "listening on [any] 6666 ...". I tried your suggestion (with "-p" before the port, else it picks a random port) and got "0.0.0.0: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host" :(

Comment: Works on Cygwin too (nc)

Comment: Great :) Works for me

Answer (score 14):

To specify a listening address:

```
nc -l -s <LISTENING_IP_ADDR> -p <LISTENING_PORT>
```

Tested on a Debian Jessie with `netcat-traditional-1.10-41`

Comment: It's not possible to use both `-l` and `-s` together.

Comment: @benedikt: some `nc` versions can, some cannot.
`nc.traditional` on Debian can:
`nc -l -s 192.168.18.100 -p 6666`
Instead `/bin/nc.openbsd` on Ubuntu cannot:
`nc -l -s 192.168.244.163 -p 6666
nc: cannot use -s and -l`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification